# Service stops when activity is closed

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, android-service

I've read a bunch of answers pertaining to this question and they all seem to be the same:

"Run your service with START_STICKY" 
"Run your service in the foreground" 
"Run your service with startService and don't bind it"

I'm doing ALL of these things, and my service STILL closes and restarts every time my activity is closed.

This is NOT an IntentService.
I'm also not calling stopSelf or stopService anywhere except in onClick handlers.

**Please scroll down to my update - This behavior has been confirmed to be a bug in the android OS and I have reported it to google.  [Click here to view the report.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104308)**

Starting my service from MainActivity:

```
svcIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MyService.class);
startService(svcIntent);
```

In my onStartCommand:

```
        // Enter foreground state
    String title = "Service has been started...";
    String subject = "Service is running...";
    String body = "Monitoring your battery usage.";
    Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.theicon, title,
            System.currentTimeMillis());
    if (prefs.getBoolean("notificationSounds", true))
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
    else
        notification.sound = null;
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    notification.setLatestEventInfo(this, subject, body, pendIntent);
    startForeground(1500, notification);
```

At the end of my onStartCommand:

```
...
// Release WakeLock
wl.release();

    return START_STICKY;
```

### UPDATE

I FIGURED OUT WHATS CAUSING IT! But I have no idea how to fix it. In my service i also use an AlarmManager inside my service to set up function calls to the service a specified time away.

```
        // Alarm manager setup for MyService
    AlarmManager AM = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    svcIntent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class);
    prefs.edit().putInt("initialBatt", initialBatt).apply();
    svcIntent1.setAction("com.myApp.servicealarm");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 93, svcIntent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    // Set the alarm
    AM.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeNow + waitTime, pendingIntent);
```

I noticed that if I DO NOT comment out the AM.set call to set an alarm, EVEN WITH AN EMPTY onReceive, my service is killed when the alarm goes off, after I swipe my app away in recent apps. If I comment out the set alarm call, then the service is never killed and keeps running after I close my app. What the heck?! I need this alarm for the functionality of my algorithms!!

It's very odd. As soon as the alarm goes off, my debug message does not print, and my service restarts. But the second time around, after the service restarts, the debug message does print and the program executes successfully.

I've tried this and it still happens with a normal broadcast receiver as well. I've also stripped my code down to ONLY the set alarm call from my service and the broadcast receiver, and the same thing occurs so it's not my algorithm. Apparantly if you have a foreground service that sets an alarm, when the alarm goes off your service restarts.

### CLOSING

This behavior seems to be caused by a bug in the android OS so I do not expect an answer. If you'd like to see this bug for yourself, [click here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104308). I've provided a project that you can compile and reproduce the problem with.

Comment: "my service STILL closes and restarts every time my activity is closed" -- how are you determining this? Are you calling `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` anywhere? Is this an `IntentService`?

Comment: @CommonsWare Because the notification disappears, and then the notification for "Service has started" pops up again within 2-3 seconds of closing the activity. I'm not calling either of those in any onDestroy or onStop methods or anything like that. and its not an IntentService. I'm baffled

Comment: it produces the same error when using getApplicationContext()?

Comment: @adheus Yes, same error. check my edit about alarmmanager for more details

Comment: How are you closing your application?

Comment: @iheanyi swiping in recent apps

Comment: Do you have any code that runs in any method when your application is closed?

Comment: @iheanyi No I don't. I don't even have onDestroy overridden

Comment: is onTaskRemoved being called?

Comment: Hmm, this is tricky. Have you tried the answer given? From what you've described, your service runs in your application's main thread. So it makes some sense that when your application is closed, your service gets closed. I'm not quite sure how that reconciles with setForeground, but it does explain the behavior that you are seeing. (SET_STICKY) would result in your service getting restarted with a null intent.

Comment: @iheanyi I assume you mean START_STICKY? I've handled my service being started with a null intent, that's not an issue. I just need it to not restart when my app is closed. I tried adding android:process=":ndservice" to the service definition in the manifest and still the service is closed when I swipe away my app on recent apps. this is incredibly aggravating

Comment: @pskink I'll override it and check

Comment: @pskink Yes. it's being called when I swipe away my app

Comment: @iheanyi It's being caused by a received broadcast to a WakefulBroadcastReceiver, but why? and how do I fix it?. Check my update I've posted what I have

Comment: I'm not sure why, but I'll continue to think about it this evening.

Comment: This looks like a bug. You might want to report it on the issue tracker.

Comment: Have you tried this on different versions of Android? What version of Android are you testing on (and what device or devices)?

Comment: @DavidWasser: I have confirmed this behavior on a Lollipop emulator.

Comment: Reported. https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=104308

Comment: @JayB  how u resolved your issue ?

Comment: @nida Send the intent as a foreground intent. See the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android kills the process when the broadcast `Intent` is sent **(before it is received/processed in your app)**.

This is a nasty Android bug, as of 4.4 (API 19).

See https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=63618&can=1&q=service%20restart%20broadcast&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars

especially comments #22 and #23

Unfortunately, almost all "open" issues were marked as "obsolete" recently, with the assumption that they were all fixed in Android 5.0. There's no way for a developer to reopen an "obsolete" issue.

---

**EDIT: Add details about foreground broadcast**

Based on the information in the linked issue, it looks like adding `Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND` to your broadcast `Intent` will ensure that the the process does not get killed on the next receipt of a broadcast `Intent`.

To do this, add:

```
svcIntent1.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
```

to the code where you set your alarm in the `AlarmManager`.

Please read the comments in the linked issue for more details.

Comment: See I thought this was strange! I knew it had to be a bug, it just makes no sense. Thanks for the link. Looks like I'll have to put in a fake message "Starting in background mode" hah

Comment: @JayB: As mentioned in comment #23, you can use a foreground `Intent` as your broadcast to work around this issue. @David, you might want to add this into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run your service in separate process. Define it in your manifest like this:

```
<service
   android:name=".path.to.service.class"
   android:process=":my_service"/>
```

Comment: Just tried it and it still closes when I swipe away my app on recent apps

Comment: I figured out what's causing the problem, please see my update, I don't know how to stop it from happening